# Config Django 1.5.1 for aptana studio 3

Tags: django, installation, aptana

How do I get Django working in aptana?  I have gooled my face off and have tried everything I could find and I still have not luck. I am using a Mac running lion.

I have django installed and in idle I can import django and call a get_version() and it works fine.
Then in aptana I think I have done everything right.  I have done an auto configure for the python interpreter and then in the libraries I have added the django directory.

> \Library\Frameworks\Python.framework\Versions\2.7\lib\python2.7\site-packages\django

When I try to create a new project I get this error:

> To get started with Django in PyDev, the pre-requisite is that Django
>   is installed in the Python / Jython / IronPython interpreter you want
>   to use (so, "import django" must properly work – if you're certain
>   that Django is there and PyDev wasn't able to find it during the
>   install process, you must go to the interpreter configuration and
>   reconfigure your interpreter so that PyDev can detect the change you
>   did after adding Django).
>
> It seems that the selected interpreter does not have Django available,
>   so, please install Django, reconfigure the interpreter so that Django
>   is recognized and then come back to this wizard.
>
> An introduction on how to get started with Django in Pydev is
>   available at: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html.

I have gone to the website and its' no help.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding just `\Library\Frameworks\Python.framework\Versions\2.7\lib\python2.7\site-packages` to the libraries

Comment: Yep that did it! Thanks! Why did I have to add that directory too?

Comment: Because `site-packages` contains `packages` which are folders that contain `modules` and other `packages`. You need to include the root so that the django package is accessible.

Comment: @Ngenator You should make it an answer so the OP accepts it and this question no longer shows as unanswered on search.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding just `\Library\Frameworks\Python.framework\Versions\2.7\lib\python2.7\site-packages` to the libraries.

The reasoning being: `site-packages` contains additional installed `packages` which are folders that contain `modules` and other `packages`. You need to include the root so that the entire `django` package is accessible (as well as any additional packages).

Comment: Why the backslashes in the path?